# How to get MVVM Light Messenger working with a PCL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mvvm-light, portable-class-library

I am currently reorganizing my WP8 project in order to have a Portable Class Library, which could result in a W8 app.

I am using MVVMLight and have the following code:

In the Portable Class Library:

```
namespace MyApp.Shared.Messages
{
    public class MyItemSelectedMessage : MessageBase
    {
        public MyItemSelectedMessage(MyItem item)
        {
            Item = item;
        }
        public MyItem Item { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my WP8 app, I still do have the ViewModels (because of Telerik and some other stuff which I cannot outsource to the PCL), where I use the following code to register for the message:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<MyItemSelectedMessage>(this, msg => SelectedItem = msg.Item);
```

The code worked fine before but now VS gives me the following error in the WP8 app at the given line:

```
The type 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.MessageBase' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight, Version=4.2.30.16997, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

In my WP8 project, I have installed MvvmLight (v4.2.30.23483) and in my PCL there are the MvvmLight Libraries for PCL (v4.2.30.16997), both up-to-date from Nuget. Do I need to downgrade a package to get the same build number, add the libraries manually or what can I do in order to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should reference the Portable.MvvmLightLibs NuGet package from both projects, and not any of the non-portable MvvmLight packages.  The Portable.MvvmLightLibs package includes support for both PCLs and platform-specific libraries.

Comment: But then I do have 2 MvvmLightLibs in my WP8 app - the one that the WP8 nuget package depends on (can't remove...), and the PCL libraries. How do I tell my code that it should use the PCL version? Or how do I replace the one the WP8 depends on with the PCL version?

Comment: @sibbl What WP8 NuGet package are you using that depends on MvvmLight?

Comment: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/ the official package, which I also used before. Adding the PCL version to the WP8 project, adds another MvvmLightLib, so that VS only gives me lots of errors because of the namespace appearing twice.

Comment: @sibbl You need to uninstall the official package from the WP8 project and install the Portable.MvvmLightLibs package instead

Comment: Incredible how easy this was... I thought the WP8 package had more magic stuff inside than the PCL. Thanks for your help, it works perfectly! :)

Comment: Yes! Thank you @DanielPlaisted. Now I can test my ViewModels =)